# What's the best way to structure data in a file, when most keys have the same value?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I'm working on a browser extension and have a set of items, that has to be mapped to some categories.

```
item-1: category-1
item-2: category-1
item-3: category-2
item-4: category-2
...
```

The mapping of the items to the categories is saved in a text file (json) but I'll only need a subset of about 60 items from all the item/category pairs when the extension runs. As keys I have a list of items and I need to search for their category in the file. There are ~200 items and 5 categories in the file.

Saving all the items as keys and the categories as their values creates a lot of redundancy. Therefore I had the idea to use the categories as keys and the items as values, like this:

```
category-1:
  item-1,
  item-2
category-2,
  item-3,
  item-4
...
```

But like this i have to iterate over all categories to search for the value I'm looking for, which is not an ideal solution.

How can I structure my data in a way, that the redundancy is minimal and the processing of the data is as fast as possible? Or is there a better way to read the data from my second example, than iterating over all the categories?

Other formats for storing the data are ok, as long as it can be processed in JavaScript.

Comment: It's not uncommon to store your data in a file differently than you maintain it in memory. If you store it in the file as you show in your second example, you can transform it to the first example on load. This assumes, of course, that you load it once and use the internal representation many times.

Answer (score 1):

> There are ~200 items and 5 categories.

At that scale you won't have to think about this at all, unless you'll be running your app on a toaster.

I'd suggest just keeping items in a flat list in your data store (akin to what a RDBMS would do with database rows).

If you need all items in a single category, use `.filter(item => item.category === something)` or similar; if you really feel like it, you can pre-cache that mapping when you load your data (or when it changes), with something like

```
const byCategory = {};
items.forEach(item =>
  (byCategory[item.category] =
    byCategory[item.category] || []).push(item)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that with such a small set of data, performance is not really an issue. I was just wondering if there would be a clever way to get the optimal performance while also optimize redundancy.